# creating jar with exploded war component in maven

Tags: java, maven, jar

I have a pom.xml which currently generate war file. I want to create a JAR and the jar which i am creating should have the two directories, one is war in the exploded form and another is some config folder.

My new jar should have below structure.

```
application.jar
|__application_war_directory
|__config folder
```

I am new to maven. Can you please anyone help me

Comment: A jar can't contain sub folders. You can create a war file or ear or zip archive which has folders.

Comment: Why does it have to be a JAR? Why not a ZIP archive?

Comment: You should look at the Maven Assembly plugin; you can configure it to create all kinds of archives. I don't have time right now to show you an example config, though. See http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/usage.html